# How to read an internal file in a web project

Tags: java, servlets, war, web-deployment, dom4j

All, Forgive me I am still learning the Java development right row.

Say we have the structure of web project like below.

The `src` and `config` is under the `Java Resources` folder of web project.

```
src
 ... 
 |- a.b.c.package
    |-test.java
 ...
config
 |-1.xml
 |-2.xml
   ...
configfolder
 |-1.properties  
 |-2.properties
testfolder
 |-test.properties
```

I want to know if I use the `dom4j`. How to read the xml file(1.xml) within the `test.java`. Thanks.

**My Experiment**

In the `test.java`. I found I can succeed to use the `class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("test.properties")` to load `test.properties` in any folders or sub folder of `src`.

Does it mean  `getResourceAsStream` can search the specified file in any of the folders of project recursively? I just can't understand it how it works. Thanks.

Comment: Check this out http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/web.1111/e13712/configurewebapp.htm#WBAPP155

Answer (score 3, accepted):

getResourceAsStream() method searches for resources with classpath as root. I suppose in your case 'testfolder' is source folder. I you would have your 1.properties in 'testfolder/mypath/1.properties' then you need to specify getResourceAsStream("mypath/1.properties")

Comment: But actually I didn't specified the relative path like `some path/1.properties` or `/some path/1.properties`. I just specified the file name `1.properties` as the parameter of `getResourceAsStream`. and It works . Why ? Thanks

Comment: Because if testfolder is resource folder then 1.properties will be in root of classpath

Comment: ah...Got it . It is true. All the properties file and xml file are in the `\WEB-INF\classes` when the war is generated. Is that reason that no need to add "/" before `"1.propertes"`? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that's the reason

Comment: Thanks you, Stan , I didn't notice that . very well design. :)

Comment: do note: ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream() as used in this code indeed searches from the root of the classpath. But there is also a Class.getResourceAsStream() which by default is relative to the package of the class you call it on.

Comment: @Gimby Ah.. Nice .So if I use the `Class.getResourceAsStream()` in the test.java. Should I put the specified file with the test.java together in the same package?  In my example , It is under the a.b.c.package .Is that right ?

Comment: I'm not making any recommendations, just warning about a common confusion that people run into. Keep using ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream() I'd say.

Comment: Oh, OK . Got it .Very good. Thanks your kind note. Helpful :)